# Repeat File Printing Using Scanner

Tags: java, intellij-idea, io, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a program which reprints the text file `simple.txt` every time the user presses "c", but with my code, it will only print once:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner fileSearch = new Scanner(new File("simple.txt"));
    UI(console, fileSearch);
}

public static void UI (Scanner console, Scanner fileSearch) {
    String choice = "Start";
    while (!choice.equals("q")) {
        System.out.print("(C)reate mad-lib, (V)iew mad-lib, (Q)uit? ");
        choice = console.next();
        choice = choice.toLowerCase();
        if (choice.equals("c")) {
            System.out.println("Create");
            CreateMadLibs(fileSearch);
        } else if (!choice.equals("q")) {
            System.out.println("I don't understand.");
        }
    }
}

public static File FileGrab (Scanner fileSearch) {
    File thing = new File(fileSearch.next());
    while (fileSearch.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println(fileSearch.nextLine());
    }
return thing;
}

public static void CreateMadLibs (Scanner fileSearch) {
    FileGrab(fileSearch);
}
```

I think the issue is that I create the scanner `fileSearch` in main instead of in `UI`. I tried initializing `fileSearch` in the `if` statement, but that gave me a fileNotFoundException.  As is, I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at test.FileGrab(test.java:28)
    at test.CreateMadLibs(test.java:36)
    at test.UI(test.java:20)
    at test.main(test.java:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `fileSearch` into the `while` loop so that it finds the `file` each time you re-search through the loop. You just call `UI(console);` in the `main` then.

Also, I would recommend closing the `scanner` at the end, as it may not be used again (unless of course `c` is re-entered).

```
public static void UI(Scanner console) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String choice = "Start";
        while (!choice.equals("q")) {
            Scanner fileSearch = new Scanner(new File("simple.txt"));
            System.out.print("(C)reate mad-lib, (V)iew mad-lib, (Q)uit? ");
            choice = console.next();
            choice = choice.toLowerCase();
            if (choice.equals("c")) {
                System.out.println("Create");
                CreateMadLibs(fileSearch);
            } else if (!choice.equals("q")) {
                System.out.println("I don't understand.");
            }
            fileSearch.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some lines in your code that functionally do nothing, I suggest to modify the `FileGrab`method by doing something like this :

```
    public static void /*File*/ FileGrab ( Scanner fileSearch ) {
    //File thing = new File(fileSearch.next());  // this line is useless
    while (fileSearch.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println(fileSearch.nextLine());
    }
    //return thing; // this either
   }
```